# Storing values in list from different code Block

Tags: c#, .net, razor

As I am new to razor and would like to need your help. I have a dynamic values on the page at different levels/paragraphs. so I would like to store these values in variable and output these values at top of the page. these varaibles are not in same view but on the same page

example:

```
    <div>result here</div>

   @{
      var name = item.name.value 
    }

   @{
      var name = item.name.value 
    }
```

So each variable name value is different and want to out put in a div at top. Please help

Comment: You will need to use jQuery or JS to retrieve a value after the div has been rendered. Otherwise, you'll need to extract the variable's value before rendering the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating an object to share information. This could be part of a 'Global Model' not the page Model.

Models are inherited top-down, so you can't share information from a View Model to a Parent-View Model.

The right path could be to share the model from the parent view to the child view.